# Eclipse LogCat shows only the first letter from each message

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I installed android SDK and plugin on eclipse 4.4, and LogCat shows only the first letter from each message.

an screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

The problem is probably in eclipse as I can see the LogCat well while running 'adb logcat'.

I tried to restart eclipse, adb, and changing LogCat fonts.

Comment: Do you see that bottom scroll bar. Scroll it to the right. Then resize the columns.

Comment: don’t working, the columns seems to be wide enough. BTW I can copy and paste a message and see the message content.

Comment: The first column is way too wide.

Comment: I cant shrink it. eclipse keep restoring the original size of the columns

Comment: I am having difficulty as well. Although I don't even get the first letter. I am using Linux Mint and as soon as I went to Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), logcat stopped function from within Eclipse, but works fine on command line. I can't go back to a previous version of Eclipse, because they have other problems on Linux that make it unusable for me. I have not found a solution yet, but I will post if I find one. I am hoping we don't have to wait for an eclipse patch that there is some other way to solve this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is how to fix it:

1. exit eclipse
2. open up the file

   > ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
3. Then cut and paste this in over the existing

   ```
   ddms.logcat.automonitor.level=error
   ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
   ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
   logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
   eclipse.preferences.version=1
   logcat.view.colsize.Application=169
   logcat.view.colsize.Time=156
   logcat.view.colsize.Tag=124
   logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
   logcat.view.colsize.Text=590
   ```
4. Restart eclipse

Comment: maybe just a typo, folder is "org.eclipse.core.runtime" (with "core")

Comment: And you may want: logcat.view.colsize.Text=xxx

Comment: Superb, Saved hours of time.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra I think you are either using mac or linux, to reveal .metadata use shortcut ctrl+h. This will reveal the hidden .metadata folder in your workspace.

Comment: yup, I am using linux..I will try this

Comment: add `logcat.view.colsize.Text=590`

Comment: Thank you! I was getting pretty desperate when Logcat didn't show anything in Eclipse Neon w/ Andmore. Based on this answer, I actually copied the configuration from old com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs to org.eclipse.andmore.ddms.prefs and that worked!

Comment: Based on other answers, I have edited clanga's answer to remove trailing spaces from the config lines.

Answer (score 12):

I'm creating a new answer since I don't have enough rep to comment on @claganga, that is , modifying the file on workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs

I'm using Eclipse Mars M4 and after trying the solution above with some variations I still could see a single column - although I could change from the single letter from debug level to TID's 4 digits.

However after having tried the following I got an important improvement:

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error  
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false  
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true  
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=169
logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=198
logcat.view.colsize.Text=619
logcat.view.colsize.Time=182
```

I'm not sure if it was moving the version line up, or removing the trailing spaces, but it started making a difference.
Now I can see Level, Time, PID, Application, Tag and Text. I'm not sure how they're supposed to change their order, but at least I can resize them with a mouse now.

However I noticed the horizontal scroll bar is still completely stuck to 100%, meaning what's out of sight is out of reach. Anyway, it's good enough for me right now.

Some important things I noticed: a) don't leave trailing spaces in any of those lines - when I copy/pasted there were some. And b) order is important , though I don't know why or how.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem on `Eclipse 4.5.0(Mars Release)`, i tried @claganga 's solution but didn't work for me at first.

Here is my addition to the solution that worked for me :

1. Exit eclipse
2. Open up the file

`~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs`

3. Just add those lines save, close it. Restart eclipse, wait for it until loading workspace. Then Exit.

`ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
    ddms.logcat.automonitor=false 
    ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
    logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
    eclipse.preferences.version=1`

4. Open up the file at step 2 again, add the lines below step 5 one at a time. After adding one line save&close it. Restart eclipse, wait for it until loading workspace. Then Exit.
5. Repeat the process at step 4 again for the second line, third line etc.

   `logcat.view.colsize.Application=169
   logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
   logcat.view.colsize.Tag=198
   logcat.view.colsize.Text=619
   logcat.view.colsize.Time=182`

Comment: Maybe, it is because of trailing spaces or ^M. But for me It works in any case.

Answer (score 4):

Like @Fabio says, don't leave trailing spaces in any of the property lines.

**This is very important!!!**

After ensuring that, you can customize the colsize of each col of these(I don't know if there're others, but I've met only these):

```
logcat.view.colsize.Application
logcat.view.colsize.Level
logcat.view.colsize.PID
logcat.view.colsize.TID
logcat.view.colsize.Tag
logcat.view.colsize.Time
logcat.view.colsize.Text
```

You don't need to care about the order of these properties because eclipse will sort them according to the alphabet.

I don't know the situations in the other systems or machines, but in my Ubuntu system, the minimum sum of all colsizes is 942. And you can set your colsize beyond that which will cause the horizontal scroll bar to display not 100%.

Hope my advice can help someone:)

Comment: I found the same thing: leaving blank spaces at the end of the line (which happens if you copy the answers above from a browser) leads to that line being ignored by eclipse. So just remove all blank spaces at the end and you'll be fine. There's no need to add settings one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eclipse Andmore the file for this problem is:

> org.eclipse.andmore.ddms.prefs

Answer (score 2):

For me all solutions worked after adding the attribute:

```
logcat.view.colsize.Text
```

If it was missing, only the level was shown. This attribute is missing in the marked correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit the file below：

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
```

Would u please try this out:
please delete the spaces at the end of each line ,it will work.
**(Most importantly, make sure there is not any space at the end of each line)**:

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.adbDebugBasePort=8600
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.info=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.name=94
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.permissions=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.size=44
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.time=34
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
devicePanel.Col0=319
devicePanel.Col1=38
devicePanel.Col4=61
eclipse.preferences.version=1
emulatorControl.track.name=155
emulatorControl.waypoint.name=95
heapPanel.col0=1276
logcat.view.colsize.Application=133
logcat.view.colsize.Level=44
logcat.view.colsize.PID=44
logcat.view.colsize.TID=44
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=98
logcat.view.colsize.Text=712
logcat.view.colsize.Time=131
logcat.view.filters.list=name\: 'com.android.settings', tag\: '', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: 'com.android.settings', level\: 'verbose', name\: 'ActivityManager', tag\: 'ActivityManager', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: '', level\: 'verbose',
logcat.view.font=1|Sans|11.0|0|GTK|1|;
threadPanel.Col0=24
threadPanel.Col1=37
threadPanel.Col2=61
threadPanel.Col3=34
threadPanel.Col4=34
threadPanel.Col5=272
threadPanel.stack.col0=503
```

Answer (score 1):

These are not the first letters from the messages.

These are the level flags: `V (for verbose)`, `D (for debug)`, etc.

Do you see that bottom scroll bar? Scroll it to the right.

Then resize the columns by clicking and dragging the separator between the headers. Do not grab the separator between the column themselves where the content is, grabbing there won't work. Also, you must reduce the size of the first column to make room for the others. And right-click on the header itself to add/remove columns.

Comment: I have only one column - Level, and I cant change the column width.

Comment: I have no separators between columns as I have only one column.
right-click on the header shows nothing...

Comment: I am stumped. I'll have to try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

goto your logcat move your bottom scroll bar towards right then on top you can drag your LEVEL  section towards left and make room for other section it will surely work

Answer (score 1):

The settings that worked for me are the following:

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=true
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=169
logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=198
logcat.view.colsize.Text=676
logcat.view.colsize.Time=156
```

> ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs

Answer (score 1):

I replaced/overwrote the `com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs` file:
    `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs`

with one from a previous Eclipse installation.  It worked.  This is the content:

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.data=82
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.info=1193
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.name=663
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.permissions=94
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.size=58
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.time=46
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
devicePanel.Col0=378
devicePanel.Col1=56
devicePanel.Col4=1273
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=98
logcat.view.colsize.Level=67
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
logcat.view.colsize.TID=54
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=168
logcat.view.colsize.Text=1001
logcat.view.colsize.Time=196
```

Answer (score 0):

1) exit eclipse

2) open up the file

> **~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs**

3) Input false vlaue for your arbitrarily parameters
[image]

[image]