# android logcat messages invisible in eclipse

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

When a run my android app via eclipse, I can select lines in logcat but no text is rendered. If I select some lines and hit "export to text file" I can see them in the exported file, but this is inconvenient.

I also get a similar problem in the DDMS view. Under "devices," I can select lines that look like they should contain text, but no text is rendered.

I'm running Eclipse Luna with the android plug-in version 23.0.3. My OS is Linux Mint 16 and I'm using Oracle's Java 1.7.0_67. I haven't had this problem in android-studio (although I have to use eclipse for various reasons).

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

I ran eclipse following this guide:

http://blog.vogella.com/2014/02/21/using-eclipse-luna-on-ubunbu/

And now text shows up in my DDMS view, but logcat now only shows the very first letter of each line (like the D for debug or W for warning). The rest is still invisible.

Comment: Did you restart your eclipse and see?

Comment: @Nabin yes, but that didn't work. Also, I tried disabling Mylyn from starting up but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue in exactly the same environment but running Mint 17. I can confirm that the text is there but it is white on white background. Using search option for known text scrolls through the LogCat lines. This is a font colour issue but android font colour preferences in eclipse are set correctly. Has to be a bug. Not found work around yet. Was hoping someone might post solution here

Comment: This works for me. [Eclipse LogCat shows only the first letter from each message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25902344)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. I only saw the letter of the Level.
No other output showed in LogCat, but when I select a line I could copy/past the text.

I finally found the solution for my problem:
The columns on in the output where all pushed to the very right edge of the screen and colapsed. I just changed the size of the columns to see all the conent.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, Kubuntu 15.04, KDE5, Eclipse Mars 4.5.0, dark theme set in OS and Eclipse.

I can see "movement" of lines in logcat, I can export it, or copy with Ctrl+C (BTW, Ctrl+C *should* work there, although context menu does not contain Copy), but the text itself in window remains invisible.

I tried also to change font/color/size, but none of that did help, it looks like the text rendering just does not happen at all.

But the background odd/even lines have different color, so some rendering is happening.

Also another suspicious thing is, that I see only "Level" column, and I can't shrink it. Remaining columns like Time, PID, TID, Application, ... are missing.

Besides that the whole Eclipse under Plasma 5 looks seriously broken, mixing up colors from both Eclipse preferences, and KDE to GTK theme enforcing.

Final fact:
I have very similar setup on second notebook (Kubuntu 15.04, KDE5, Eclipse Luna 4.4.2), and it works there.
The only big visual difference is, that the Luna on the other notebook is visually not broken, and I kept it in classic light colors. And I have no special DPI settings there (the invisible logcat KDE5 has 141 DPI setting).

I can't decide, whether it's KDE5/Plasma5 settings interfering with Eclipse rendering, or if it's just Eclipse bug, is Linux Mint KDE based? Or do you use dark theme?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Eclipse Mars in Arch with Xfce enviroment. It appeared to be related to GTK. I tried two solutions that worked for me:

**1** Export variable before launch eclipse:

`export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse`

You can do it by terminal on every launch, or just edit your /bin/eclipse file - add `export SWT_GTK3=0` before the `exec ...` line

**2** In eclipse.ini add:

`--launcher.GTK_version
2`

before the `--launcher.appendVmargs` line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but try this. If you can select the text in Logcat you can just select the text then type control c. that's the copy shortcut for windows. use command c for mac. then open a text editor and paste it in.

Comment: Thanks, but ctrl-c doesn't work in logcat. There is no "copy" option on the right-click menu either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: go to DDMS  view and select the emulator or device you have been using to test if it is not selected then come back to java prospective and check logcat this has helped me may be it will help you

Comment: Also, I have often noted that logcat content can be easily exported to log file if the line is a system.out.println() or a logger note but it may not export for other outputs many many times restarting emulator helps

Comment: This is a known workaround for a problem where there is no text. Does not apply to this problem where the text font colour is white and white background

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with the following setup:

- Linux Mint Debian 64 with Mate (UP8)
- Eclipse Luna 4.4.1
- Oracle Java SDK 1.8.0.25

For me it helped to download "Eclipse Keplar" for Android development. It seems to be a known Bug with Eclipse Luna