# Eclipse Mars DDMS only shows first letter in Level and no Messages

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ddms, eclipse-mars

I upgraded Eclipse Luna to Mars. Now in my DDMS perspective, the only column available was the Level and there only the first letter of each entry was shown (as here: [Eclipse LogCat shows only the first letter from each message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010393/eclipse-logcat-shows-only-the-first-letter-from-each-message)). In order to fix this I changed my

/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs

I added

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error  
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false  
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true  
logcat.view.colsize.Level=54  
eclipse.preferences.version=1  
logcat.view.colsize.Application=169  
logcat.view.colsize.Time=156  
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=124  
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54  
logcat.view.colsize.Messages=100
```

However, still the level only displays the first character and the Messages column is missing, even though I specified it in the preferences.

Really, all of these entries should be visible by default. How can I get them to work in Eclipse Mars?

Answer (score 1):

Change .Messages=100 to .Text=100
It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to :
**/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/**
And open the file **com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs** using any editor and copy the following code to that file. It will surely work.

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.data=73
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.info=76
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.name=239
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.permissions=76
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.size=120
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.time=42
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
devicePanel.Col0=117
devicePanel.Col1=51
devicePanel.Col4=68
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=219
logcat.view.colsize.Level=29
logcat.view.colsize.PID=50
logcat.view.colsize.TID=50
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=143
logcat.view.colsize.Text=543
logcat.view.colsize.Time=130
threadPanel.Col0=32
threadPanel.Col1=44
threadPanel.Col2=72
threadPanel.Col3=45
threadPanel.Col4=45
threadPanel.Col5=280
threadPanel.stack.col0=515
```