# How to make Eclipse LogCat display all columns?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

Basically I have the exact same problem as this guy:

[Eclipse LogCat shows only the first letter from each message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010393/eclipse-logcat-shows-only-the-first-letter-from-each-message)

But the answer provided does not work for me. The accepted answer tells to go to this location and do some stuff:

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
```

However when I try to go there, I don't have the "com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs" file. If I check what files are there, I get this:

[image: Contents of the folder]

As you can see, not even a mention of anything android.

So how do I fix this? Maybe there is some package I should've installed but haven't?

Also, I'm using Eclipse 4.5.0 (Mars) on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, just create the file with the name : `com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs` you already written.

After that for invisible log messages and columns : I made it work by making one change at a time like this:

First just add those lines and save the file, restart Eclipse.

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error  
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false  
eclipse.preferences.version=1  
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true  
logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
```

Exit eclipse, add the lines below one at a time, restart eclipse, exit eclipse.. repeat the process for all lines once.

```
logcat.view.colsize.Application=169  
logcat.view.colsize.Time=156  
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=124  
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54  
logcat.view.colsize.Text=202
```

At the end of this annoying process, you should have all columns in logcat that you had written on that file.(`com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs`)

Answer (score 2):

Put the following content into `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs` (`.metadata` folder exists in your Eclipse workspace dirctory):

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.adbDebugBasePort=8600
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.info=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.name=94
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.permissions=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.size=44
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.time=34
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
devicePanel.Col0=319
devicePanel.Col1=38
devicePanel.Col4=61
eclipse.preferences.version=1
emulatorControl.track.name=155
emulatorControl.waypoint.name=95
heapPanel.col0=1276
logcat.view.colsize.Application=133
logcat.view.colsize.Level=44
logcat.view.colsize.PID=44
logcat.view.colsize.TID=44
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=98
logcat.view.colsize.Text=712
logcat.view.colsize.Time=131
logcat.view.filters.list=name\: 'com.android.settings', tag\: '', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: 'com.android.settings', level\: 'verbose', name\: 'ActivityManager', tag\: 'ActivityManager', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: '', level\: 'verbose',
logcat.view.font=1|Sans|11.0|0|GTK|1|;
threadPanel.Col0=24
threadPanel.Col1=37
threadPanel.Col2=61
threadPanel.Col3=34
threadPanel.Col4=34
threadPanel.Col5=272
threadPanel.stack.col0=503
```

You may need to repeat this if you create a new workspace and switch into it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After deleting the spaces behind the columns, logcat finally displays all columns. I already had given up on logcat in eclipse ever working properly.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse neon that used andmore plugin , just edit `org.eclipse.andmore.ddms.prefs` in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory.
and past this codes, then restart eclipse.

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Level=838
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
eclipse.preferences.version=1
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
logcat.view.colsize.Application=169
logcat.view.colsize.Time=156
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=124
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
logcat.view.colsize.Text=202
```